# How to markup python functions with directives that can be processed to generate a flow chart of what is going on?

Tags: python

I would like to be able to generate a flow chart for a package. Where each function contains

```
def func():
"""
:flow_chart_directive name: A directive giving some information on what calls this function
"""
```

Does a tool like this for python exist?

I'm thinking the ability to display python code in graphical format, the flow and what is going on, could help someone catch up on what is going on. Almost like a block program where you have a **main** file pointing to a block that is a `Package`, then you can double click on the `Package` and it has the interactions of the package showing up with the `""" _information_ """` in blocks for each function and arrows pointing around to what's going on.

Comment: If you can get your hands on a license, SciTools Understand has a feature doing exactly what you want: https://scitools.com/features/

Comment: Maybe I'll have to write my own open source version someday.